# How can I set a uintptr_t value to address of non uintptr_t function?

Tags: c++, casting

```cpp
void __fastcall func1(void*  ptr, int edxReg) 
{
    int a = 5;
}
```

I want to take this function's address and set it to a `uintptr_t` variable:

```cpp
std::uintptr_t addr = &func1;
```

However, I cannot do this, since it cannot convert from `void(__fastcall)(void* , int)` to `uintptr_t`.

I tried using C++ style casting, but have had no luck with it, it just gives me a random value.

What can I do about this? The function named `func1` must stay as is, it must be a `void __fastcall` with 2 parameters, so that can't be changed.

Comment: *"tried using c++ style casting but it no luck with it, it just gives me a random value."* A seemingly random value is to be expected, for an address.

Comment: _"it just gives me a random value"_ beyond whether it's random (it is not) what integer value were you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

A C++-style cast is appropriate here, specifically [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast):

> Only the following conversions can be done with reinterpret_cast, except when such conversions would cast away constness or volatility.
> ...
>
> 2. A pointer can be converted to any integral type large enough to hold all values of its type (e.g. to std::uintptr_t)
> 3. A value of any integral or enumeration type can be converted to a pointer type. A pointer converted to an integer of sufficient size and back to the same pointer type is guaranteed to have its original value, otherwise the resulting pointer cannot be dereferenced safely (the round-trip conversion in the opposite direction is not guaranteed; the same pointer may have multiple integer representations) The null pointer constant NULL or integer zero is not guaranteed to yield the null pointer value of the target type; static_cast or implicit conversion should be used for this purpose.
>
> ...

So, for example:

```cpp
void __fastcall func1(void* ptr, int edxReg) 
{
    int a = 5;
}

std::uintptr_t addr = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(&func1);
```

And then when needed, you can cast the `uintptr_t` back to a function pointer of appropriate signature in order to call the function being pointed at, eg:

```cpp
typedef void __fastcall (*funcType)(void*, int);
// or: using funcType = void __fastcall (*)(void*, int);

funcType func = reinterpret_cast<funcType>(addr);
func(somePtr, someEdxRegVal);
```